# R - Extracting number of columns of a dataframe whose values contain a certain pattern

Tags: r, split, aggregate

I want to get the following column of the column that contains an "F" in the columns from 6 on (all with the V).

I tried to use a subset of the DF, that only contains the columns starting with V. When I use my function, on that, it gives me nothing, but when I use the same function on the original DF, it works. That seems to be because I get more than one result then. I tested it on other subsets and my function only works with more than 1 result.

```
   Frq             Code     ICD   Condition Variable V01_Code V01_Corr V01_Lag V02_Code V02_Corr V02_Lag 
1   1 A00-A09_DJF_DJF_PC1 A00-A09       DJF  DJF_PC1     S1FI    -0.55   L6/L7     <NA>       NA    <NA>


which(names(DF)%in%c(colnames(DF[ , grepl( "F" , DF) ]))) +1
[1] 3 5 6 7
```

The result is correct, but I only need the columns starting with V, so I did a subset:

```
Splitframe = DF[,6:ncol(DF)

  V01_Code V01_Corr V01_Lag V02_Code V02_Corr V02_Lag
1     S1FI    -0.55   L6/L7     <NA>       NA    <NA>

which(names(DF)%in%c(colnames(Splitframe[ , grepl( "F" , Splitframe) ]))) +1
numeric(0)
```

What is wrong there? Is it because of the c()?

The next step after getting the column-numbers is to calculate the mean of those. When there is no result matching in the previous step, it should be an NA as mean.

My DF:

```
structure(list(Frq = 1L, Code = "A00-A09_DJF_DJF_PC1", ICD = "A00-A09", 
Condition = "DJF", Variable = "DJF_PC1", V01_Code = "S1FI", 
V01_Corr = -0.55, V01_Lag = "L6/L7", V02_Code = NA_character_, 
V02_Corr = NA_real_, V02_Lag = NA_character_), class = "data.frame", row.names = "1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `data.frame`, when there is a single column/row, it drops the dimensions as by default it is `drop = TRUE` if we check the `?Extract`

> x[i, j, ... , drop = TRUE]

> drop - For matrices and arrays. If TRUE the result is coerced to the lowest possible dimension (see the examples). This only works for extracting elements, not for the replacement. See drop for further details.

Or can be checked specifically with `?"[.data.frame"`

> drop - logical. If TRUE the result is coerced to the lowest possible dimension. The default is to drop if only one column is left, but not to drop if only one row is left.

thus the OP's code returns a vector with no column names

```
Splitframe[ , grepl( "F" , Splitframe)]
[1] "S1FI"
```

whereas if we add `drop = FALSE`

```
Splitframe[ , grepl( "F" , Splitframe), drop = FALSE]
 V01_Code
1     S1FI
```

and the whole code returns

```
which(names(DF)%in%c(colnames(Splitframe[ , grepl( "F" , 
          Splitframe), drop = FALSE ]))) +1
[1] 7
```